# What's the use of static/extern in source files?

Tags: c, static, scope, extern

I have a very mixed notion of what happens when I compile many files - mostly when it comes to the visibility of things from one file to an other. From what I read, `static` limits the scope of a variable or function to the file itself. `extern` does the opposite. From that I would expect to be able and simply read a *global extern* from any file. That doesn't work in practice though as seen below.

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", b); // b is extern global
    return 0;
}
```

**a.c:**

```
static int a = 40;
```

**b.c:**

```
extern int b = 20;
```

I can't even compile:

```
> gcc main.c a.c b.c -o test
b.c:1:12: warning: ‘b’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
 extern int b = 20;
            ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:20: error: ‘b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf("%d\n", b); // b is extern global
```

Comment: It is a good idea to have all your extern variables in .h files and include them in required .c files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing all wrong.When we writing `extern int b` it means an integer type variable called `b` has been declared.And we can do this declaration as many times as needed. (remember that declaration can be done any number of times).By externing a variable we can use the variables anywhere in the program provided we know the declaration of them and the variable is defined somewhere.

The correct way is

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int b;   //declaration of b
 int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", b); // using b 
    return 0;
}
```

**b.c:**

```
int b = 20;   //definition here
```

and compile as `gcc main.c b.c -o test`

I have omitted a.c as it was doing nothing in this example.
To understand more about externs see this site.Its having very good content http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/

Comment: Thanks, that was the simplest explanation of the bunch :)

Comment: `extern int b;` why do we need extern here global variables are extern by default

Comment: Look at the link i have shown and comment by R.Sahu

Comment: @Shan What comment and even if you remove extern your code doesn't change so why have it and what is the significance of having it?

Comment: @Gopi check Sorry R Sahu's answer. And "even if you remove extern your code doesn't change"  what does it mean?

Comment: @Shan True, `extern` is set by default. However being explicit makes things clearer - so it's just a convention in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be used if it is either declared or defined.

In `main.c`, there is no declaration of `b`. You can add

```
extern int b;
```

in `main.c` for the compiler to be able to use `b`.  This declares to the compiler that `b` is defined somewhere else and it is of type `int`.

In `b.c`, you can remove the word `extern`. Unless qualified with `static`, it is `extern` by default.

```
int b = 20;
```

Even in `b.c`, you can use a declaration at the top of the file and define it at the bottom.

```
extern int b;

//
// ... code that uses b
//

int b = 20;
```

The `extern` line simply declares the variable. The last line defines the variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `extern` variable the compiler knows that the declaration for this variable is here and definition is somewhere else.

So you can do as shown below

**some.h**

```
   extern int b;  /* Declare the variable */
```

**b.c**

```
   int b = 20;  /* Define the variable */
```

**main.c**

```
    #include<some.h>

    int main()
    {
       printf("%d\n",b);  /* Use the variable b */

       return 0;
    }
```

With this now the file main.c knows the declaration of `b` since it is there is `some.h` file.

Comment: including some.h is not necessary i guess